# Drop down menu CSS advice needed

Tags: html, css

Here is my [codepen.](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/Mperdy)

**Question 1**

How I can change the background and text colour of the drop down menu my navigation bar on my webpage? Just for answer purposes I wanted the text to be white and the background colour to be grey. (I'm not asking for anyone to do it for me just trying to make things clear)

**Question 2**

At the moment in time within my coding, when I hover over the navigation bar text in the drop down menu at the bottom of the box an underline appears. However, I want the underline to appear under each text of each webpage when the user hovers over it instead of at the bottom of the navigation bar drop down menu box.

**Any helpful links with identifying classes?**

In addition, in terms of the the navigation bar html I'm finding it hard to identify the class name for what does what therefore, when I do my CSS I can easily identify what class I need to write. As a result of this, I was wondering if anyone has any good helpful tutorial links which can help me with this.

**HTML code**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Liam Docherty | London Web Developer &amp; GFX designer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="Your Brand Name"></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>


    <section class="section1">
        <div class="hero"></div>




        <a href= "#section2"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section class="section2" id = "section2">



        <a href = "#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

    </section>
    <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section">

    </section>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

<footer></footer>

</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default {
        background-color: #4D5061;
        height: 10vh;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14pt;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        right: 50%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        height: 3px;
        background-color:red;
        border-radius: 9px;
        transition:all .2s;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
        color: red;
    }
    .nav.navbar-nav, .nav.navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    a:hover {
        color:red;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    #logo {
        padding-top: 2vh;
        padding-left: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
    section {
        position: relative;
    }
    .section1 {
        height: 90vh;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .section2 {
        height: 95vh;
        background-color: #A59E8C;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
    }
    .contact_section {
        height: 93vh;
        background-color: grey;
    }
    .fa-angle-down {
        color: #4D5061;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    footer {
        height: 5vh;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1 Answer:**

For question 1 answer read the https://stackoverflow.com/users/7650566/rcruey 's answer. By that system, you can add background color and text color.

***Note:*** Background color and the color are the basics of CSS. If you have enough time, you need to learn more about CSS first.

**Question 2 Answer:**

To underline  under each text of each webpage when the user hovers over it. It's so simple. Just make the code for your paragraph and the link.

```
    p, a{
         text-decoration: none;
     }

    p:hover, a:hover{
         text-decoration:none;
    }
```

and avoid this code for navigation bar just add this for navigation bar menu specially, which is done in question 1:

```
    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
            background-color: grey;
    }

   .dropdown .dropdown-menu a{
      color: white;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
       text-decoration: underline;
       text-decoration-color: black;
     }
```

**And finally for suggestion :**

I want to say that, you may be try to overwrite the bootstrap class in your code.

For this, use inspect element of Chrome or Firefox. By clicking on the above field and click Inspect element. Then you will see which class or id's are used for the above style-sheet.

And to get perfect result using bootstrap over-righting... in your index.html page, correctly link up the styles. Try to link up **bootstrap.min.css** first and then add your own **style.css**.  This will give you a perfect result.

Comment: Sorry for question two I didn't mean for a paragraph. You see the nav bar text when you hover over it you get a red line under it? I want the same for the drop down menu text and each page for the drop down menu to be one after the other and in the centre. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I found the answer to that don't worry:)

Comment: Already said thanks in my other comment:) However, once again thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to adding color inside of elements you want to make sure you are specific with the details. For example with what you gave me I figured this out.
Insert this in your CSS document and tell me if this is what you mean. If so just make sure you have one element (Menu for example) selected for the background color, and then the next element (navbar or a links for another example.) To color the next element.

Also for an`enter code here` easy fix for underlining font, just use a text-decoration command. Solid border-bottom 1px etc. I hope this helped.

```
     .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
        background-color: grey;


    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a{
        color: white;

    }

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
     text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: black;
    -moz-text-decoration-color:black;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, this has helped me find a solution with my question one. However, do you know a solution to question 2?

Comment: Same concept, but use text-decoration{}

Comment: Doesn't appear to work? Try it on my codepen. http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/Mperdy

Comment: How about trying this.    

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li{
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-decoration-color: black;
        -moz-text-decoration-color:black;
    }

Comment: Oh sorry I was thinking you meant the lines always appearing. Use an a::hover command to have the underline appear. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem, what do I write after 'a::hover'?

Comment: .dropdown .dropdown-menu a:hover{
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-decoration-color: black;
        -moz-text-decoration-color:black;
    }

This way it retains in those elements.

Comment: I used your link and saved the pen. I don't know if you get to see the change or not but I did edit the code to where it works. But the bottom of the navbar still gets highlighted, but the words of the link that is hovered over does work on that end. I'll take a look and see if I can help out more than this.

Comment: I found the issue. 
        .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: 50%;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            height: 3px;
            background-color:red;
            border-radius: 9px;
            transition:all .2s;
        }
Remove the red from the background color and that will fix the issue with the red line appearing on the bottom.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean on the nav bar I mean I want the underline red line to be under the text on the drop down menu text right under it not at the bottom of the box. Have a look at my codepen if you don't understand what I mean.

Comment: You see like the nav bar text when you hover over it you get a red line under it? I want the same for the drop down menu text and each page for the drop down menu to be one after the other. Thanks for all your help!